# How to run React function from backend (Express) code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, express

I use React TypeScript and I have a function like this:

```
// Home.tsx
const setLoadingTextFunction = (text: string) => {
        setLoadingText(text)
    }
```

and I want to run this function from the backend code every time it the status in loading phase.
So for example when the program is downloading a file I want it to run `setLoadingTextFunction("Downloading server files...")`

I already asked AI and it said that I needed to export the function and import it to the backend but I couldn't do it

Comment: Of course you couldn't do that, it makes absolutely no sense. Code running on the server cannot directly call code running in arbitrary client browsers.

Comment: To clarify, is your frontend downloading a file from the server? If so, why do you have to "call" that function from the backend? Just set the loadingText as soon as you start your download on client side.

Answer (score -1):

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  const [loadingText, setLoadingText] = useState('');

  const setLoadingTextFunction = (text: string) => {
    setLoadingText(text);
  };

  // Function to update loading text via API call
  const updateLoadingText = (newText: string) => {
    fetch('/api/updateLoadingText', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ text: newText }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your UI */}
      <p>{loadingText}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/updateLoadingText', (req, res) => {
  const { text } = req.body;
  // Update loading text on the client-side (e.g., via websockets or other real-time techniques)
  // You can also log it or store it as needed for your server logic.
  console.log(`New loading text: ${text}`);
  res.send('Loading text updated');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```